# Missing Angularjs HTML elements in Phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

I am crawling a website. I must change the date of the given job when suddenly I realized that the element is missing. When I screen capture it, the element is really missing. Is there any way to render that element? The website runs with Angularjs because I noticed the `ng` in the HTML code. Here are the pictures, the first one is the desktop capture and the second one is from the phantomjs.

[Normal date in web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYmj5.png)

[No date, straight to the next label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doijb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve this, just wait for the angularjs to load on phantomjs. It takes an estimate of 5 seconds before it loads. The best to do here is `setTimeout` function.